# Exchange 2019 Antimalware engine updates download but don't get applied

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2019, exchange-2019

I've been diagnosing for the past day or so some issues with an Exchange 2019 server related to Antimalware filtering/scanning. This was disabled on our server, I enabled it, and restarted the transport service per the Microsoft docs:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antimalware-protection/antimalware-procedures?view=exchserver-2019#use-the-exchange-management-shell-to-enable-or-disable-malware-filtering-on-mailbox-servers
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antimalware-protection/download-antimalware-updates?view=exchserver-2019

In Event Viewer, however, we're getting some logs that indicate this isn't working:

```
Event 6031, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process has successfully downloaded updates for Microsoft.

Event 6034, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process is testing the Microsoft scan engine update

Event 6035, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process was unsuccessful in testing an engine update. 
 Engine: Microsoft
```

It looks like it fails for some reason and logs "MS Filtering Engine Update process was unsuccessful in testing an engine update."

Then the process repeats and we can see it trying again:

```
Event 7003, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process has successfully scheduled all update jobs.

Event 6024, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process is checking for new engine updates.
 Scan Engine: Microsoft 
 Update Path: http://amupdatedl.microsoft.com/server/amupdate

Event 6030, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process is attempting to download a scan engine update.
 Scan Engine: Microsoft
 Update Path: http://amupdatedl.microsoft.com/server/amupdate.

Event 6031, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process has successfully downloaded updates for Microsoft.

Event 6034, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process is testing the Microsoft scan engine update

Event 6035, FIPFS: MS Filtering Engine Update process was unsuccessful in testing an engine update. 
 Engine: Microsoft
```

The configuration settings look fine and we've allowed both amupdatedl.microsoft.com and forefrontdl.microsoft.com through the firewall. (It appears that's working because it says downloaded successfully in the Event Viewer logs.)
[image: Configuration Settings / Status]

Any ideas / help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: One other note, it does seem to be trying to download and use some of the scan engine updates as evidenced by this staging folder here with recent timestamps.
[image: Scan engine temp file downloads]

I also found some other resources that suggested a permissions issue, but I checked and Network Service has full permissions to E:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FIP-FS\Data

Things I've looked at:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/832e155e-054a-4e1c-8ce0-41a778abe8ff/exchange-2016-cu11-antimalware-automatic-update-fails?forum=Exch2016MFSM
- http://www.networksteve.com/exchange/topic.php/Error_of_Get-EngineUpdateInformation_in_Exchange_2013/?TopicId=56872&Posts=3
- https://martijnwestera.blogspot.com/2015/08/exchange-2013-built-in-anti-malware-ms.html
- https://www.reddit.com/r/exchangeserver/comments/2kvxj5/updating_antimalware_engine_in_ex2013cu6/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ehlro/exchange-2013-malware-engine-updates-troubleshooting
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/09b9b26e-5898-42de-958d-ab967398bab8/error-id-6027-ms-filtering-engine-update-process-was-unsuccessful-in-contacting-the-primary-update?forum=exchangesvrgeneral
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/download-engine-and-definition-updates-exchange-2013-help?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Same issue on my side with the same date than Susanne. The latest successful update is on the 8th of December, all updates since then are in error. Using Exchange 2016 CU21

Comment: Same issue here with the same date. I noticed that the following FIP-FS executables were updated in the latest Exchange security update:
EngineUpdateServiceInterfaces.dll
Pipeline2.dll
ScanEngineTest.exe
scanningprocess.exe
fms.exe
FSCSqmUploader.exe
NavigatorParser.dll
Wonder if they broke something? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-microsoft-exchange-server-2019-2016-and-2013-november-9-2021-kb5007409-7e1f235a-d41b-4a76-bcc4-3db90cd161e7

Comment: Short question, we have the same issue on some exchange servers and we get this after reboot our servers because of an sophos endpoint update on 8th of December. Do you also use sophos endpoint?

Comment: We also have a client's Exchange 2016 server with Sophos exhibiting the same issue

Comment: Not using sophos here, so I don't think that's the root cause. @Minkus it seems plausible they broke something.

Comment: Realised I didn't mention but ours is Exchange 2013 CU23. Thought it might be virus scanner but have checked logs and it has blocked nothing. Here's another report (same date etc) https://petermorrissey.blogspot.com/2021/12/exchange-server-fips-fs-error.html

Answer (score 2):

Got this event since the 8th of December on 2 Exchange 2016 and 2 Exchange 2019 Servers. Looks like a common problem with both download paths. No Updates since then.
Engine            : Microsoft
LastChecked       : 12.10.2021 11:42:51  +01:00
LastUpdated       : 12.08.2021 01:13:24  +01:00
EngineVersion     : 1.1.18700.4
SignatureVersion  : 1.353.2243.0
SignatureDateTime : 12.07.2021 06:41:19  +01:00
UpdateVersion     : 2112070009
UpdateStatus      : UpdateAttemptFailed

14th of december: I opened a MS Ticket. Let's see..

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research, here are many things cause this issue, you could use FPSDiag.exe (E:\Exchange Server\FIP-FS\bin) to generate a log to analyse this error.

In addition, I have found a similar [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/7c535bae-8c21-418a-b459-8943408672da/antimalware-updates?forum=exchangesvrgeneral) and there are some discussions on this issue for your reference and hope it is helpful to you.

Related blog: [Problem z aktualizacją Antimalware w Exchange 2013](http://pepugmaster.blogspot.com/2013/08/problem-z-aktualizacja-antimalware-w.html)

Answer (score 1):

good news: since this morning the updates are working again. Maybe because of my post on the exchange team blog or because of my MS Ticket. Look for yourself. Everythings fine :)

Comment: We've managed to get updating working on Exchange 2013 CU23 which is great.

However when I run the Enable-AntimalwareScanning.ps1 and start the 'Microsoft Filtering Management Service', I still get FIPS-FS Scan Process Failed errors (0x80010105) and Application Error on scanningprocess.exe (0xc0000005) - see the following blog post - and mail flow is still disrupted... same for you?
https://petermorrissey.blogspot.com/2021/12/exchange-server-fips-fs-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue (FIPS-FS Scan Process Failed errors (0x80010105) and Application Error on scanningprocess.exe (0xc0000005)) and in addition to running the https://aka.ms/ResetScanEngineVersion script provided by Microsoft I also ran the official HealthChecker script at https://microsoft.github.io/CSS-Exchange/Diagnostics/HealthChecker/

This revealed that the Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package had been removed from the server, an Exchange prerequisite - once reinstalled, the malware scanner component worked properly again :)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-2013-prerequisites-exchange-2013-help